# Integrate Metamask in Electron

Tags: web3js, metamask

**Hello guys**,

Is there any of you who have tried to add metamask to electron.js. I wasn't able to find any relevant sources. My goal is to create desktop dapp. If you have any articles or advices will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask is a browser extension so you would need to open a web browser by definition.

Instead try WalletConnect.org

Answer (score 0):

This article is a very nice walkthrough of various issues and solutions: https://medium.com/swapynetwork/integrating-metamask-with-electron-a-simple-secure-and-non-intrusive-approach-517a04da1656